# How to specify profile of dependent war?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a multi-module maven project which has profiles set up. So if I want to use my mock version I can specify:

```
mvn clean install -Pmock
```

How can I replicate this in another project's pom which is going to have this mock implementation as a dependency?

I tried the following, but the profile tag is seen as invalid:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest.service</artifactId>
    <profile>mock</profile>
    <type>war</type>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a parent pom where you define and activate the profile, but don't configure it.  The configuration will stay with the dependent module.

In your parent pom you would have something like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
         <id>mock</id>
         <activation>
             <property>useMock</property>
             <value>true</value>
         </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then in your module you can configure that profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>mock</id>
        ...Profile Stuff Here
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Ah, so the parent pom's profile gets loaded down the hierarchy to modules. Cool.